# Watch OS 2 Issue to set an Image

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I just want to add an image to my WKInterfaceController but...

Xcode tells me :

> Unable to find image named "circle44" on Watch

```
@IBOutlet var cirlceImage: WKInterfaceImage!
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    cirlceImage.setImageNamed("circle44")
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay I found the result the image have to be in your WatchKt App not on your Extension. And with the addition of app thinning the watch no longer searches for 1x images as they should all be 2x. [image: As you see in works !]

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    @IBOutlet var cirlceImage: WKInterfaceImage!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        cirlceImage.setImageNamed("circle94")


    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()

    }
}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, using setImageNamed("image_name") works, but setImage(UIImage(named:"image_name")) does not.

Answer (score 0):

Add images into imagees.xcassets select Apple Watch then add 2x into there

[image]