# Unable to find image named "img.png" on Watch after updated to OS 2 and xcode 7?

Tags: ios, watchkit

All the images work on OS 1. So today after updating to OS2, the images stop working.  I tried to clean the build and the same problem exists.

Also tried to remove the image asset folder and re-added it to back to xcode.  But still no help.

Anyone knows what's wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Ans: I moved my 1x image to 2x in the asset folder and it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watch OS 2 Issue to set an Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281009/watch-os-2-issue-to-set-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

click on the image file and go to right side and select all for "Target Membership" options like screen shot below, Clean the build and try again.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add both watch os & watch extension target while adding the image [image]